# Microsoft Access VBA code to send email to recipients with attachment based on results of query filtered on check date

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, attachment, office-automation

I've commented out the section to add the attachment because I know it works, but the files currently aren't present to be attached.  I'm new to VBA and am missing something.  My data is simply employee number, check date (send_checkdt), check number, name, etc.  The query has no parameters, which is why I'm doing the select based on the form date defined in strSQL.

When I run it I immediately get an over and it exits. Previously I was only able to send the email to the first person in the query and the record didn't advance. The email part is working correctly, I'm just not processing the data correctly.as

What am I missing?

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim Msg As String
    Dim F_attach As String
    Dim O As Outlook.Application
    Dim M As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim DT As String
    DT = Forms!Form1!frmCheckDt
    
    Dim strSQL As String
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM qryMailList Where send_checkdt=" & DT
    
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim Mlist As DAO.Recordset
    'Dim Mfiltered As DAO.Recordset
    
    
    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set Mlist = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
    
    Set O = New Outlook.Application
    Set M = O.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    
       Mlist.MoveFirst
       
        Do Until Mlist.EOF
            Msg = "Dear " & Mail_FullName & "," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                     "Your payroll check number " & Send_CheckNo & " was deposited on " & _
                send_checkdt & " for " & Format(Send_NetPay, "Currency") & "." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                "Sincerely," & vbCrLf & Send_CoName
                
            F_attach = "f:\archives\CK" & Mail_emp & "_" & Send_CheckNo & ".pdf"
                
            With M
                .BodyFormat = olFormatPlain
                .Body = Msg
                .To = Mail_Email
                .Subject = "Direct Deposit " & send_checkdt
               ' .Attachments.Add F_attach
                .Display
                
                
            End With
            
            Mlist.MoveNext
            
        Loop
        DoCmd.Close
        
    
    Set M = Nothing
    Set O = Nothing
    Set Mlist = Nothing
    Set dbs = Nothing
    Set qdf = Nothing
    Set Mfiltered = Nothing
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried to run the code under the debugger attached? Do you get any errors at runtime?

Comment: I added 3 watch variables from my query and they display the first record up until the Mlist.MoveFirst when I try to proceed from that point in the debugger I get an error 3021 - no current record.

Comment: That is a good indicator the `Mlist.MoveFirst` should be excluded or replace by any alternative.

Comment: If you're getting the error on the call to `MoveFirst`, that means that there were no rows returned by your `SELECT` statement. This is most likely caused by your not properly formatting the date value that you're concatenating to the SQL statement.

Comment: I  added format function for the date variable  so it matched the format stored in the table.  Still didn't work. I also just changed the OpenRecordset to use a table instead of query.  It still gets an over.  Everything works outside of VBA.  I even created a report using the query to make sure it listed all of the data.  Could I be missing a reference?  When I first tested the email component I was using the query as the data source for the form with the criteria for date in the query.  This way it produced the email for the first record in the file.

Comment: send_checkdt is a date/time field? Try: `"SELECT * FROM qryMailList Where send_checkdt=#" & DT & "#"`

Comment: Took the select out and used the full table just to check results.  Still over.

Comment: send_checkdt is a date/time field

Comment: What is "get an over"? If there is an error message, edit your question to provide.

Comment: Code is not using recordset to pull data. If  `Mail_FullName` is a field of recordset, then need to prefix with recordset name `Mlist.Mail_FullName`. Same for other recordset field references. If this code is behind a form that is bound to data with those field names, then values are coming from one record of form, not recordset. So code is looping recordset but not pulling data from recordset, just the same record on form for each loop.

Answer (score 0):

I moved

set O=New Outlook.Application and
set M=O.CreateItem(olMailItem)

to be below

Do Until Mlist.EOF  and it works correctly.

I also had to further identify my data fields by adding Mlist! to each.  Without identifying Mlist it prodcued the correct number of emails but no data was filled in.  Thank you to everyone that offered comments.